# Clonezilla won't clone drive that has Win 7 Pro upgrade (from win 7 Home Premium)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, clone

I have used Clonezilla to clone a disk which has Win 7 Home premium. During the process using the disk to disk cloning, Clonezilla shows that two partitions are cloned; the 100meg partition and the rest of the disk partition. It is cloned successfully though.

After upgrading Win7 Home to Win 7 Pro, the disk can't be cloned with the automatic disk to disk cloning method. The report from Clonezilla is that there are 4 partitions the original disk and that the target and the partitions are too small for the source partitions (but it only tries to clone two partitions).

Does the Win 7 Pro upgrade mess with something in the partition table?

Is there a way around this using the expert settings?

This is a repeatable phenomenon as I have tried it at least a dozen times with different disks.

An original Win 7 Pro installation clones fine. It's just the upgraded version.

Comment: No;  The upgrade anytime process does not modify the partitions.

Comment: After upgrading from Win7 home to Win7 Pro, there are 4 partitions created by clonezilla on the target harddrive where  there were are 2 reported on the source harddrive, so something is going on that prevent Clonezilla from cloning the disk correctly. Clonezilla wants to copy the files to the wrong partitions that are created.